# Android here sdk Offline truck routing gives No connectivity error

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to develop a navigation app for trucks and cars, but the route calculation not works offline for Trucks just for cars. I have 90 day trial for premium sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download any map data? Truck routing requires map data to be downloaded via MapLoader to work offline.

Comment: Sure, i have downloaded map data. As i said the car offline routing works fine, but when i change to truck routing, it can't calculate the route.

Comment: Make sure to update the map version. The truck data was a newly introduced data layer.

Comment: What SDK version are you using? Offline is only supported in v3.2.2 or higher.

Comment: Now i have added the sdk v3.3, now i'm getting INVALID_OPERATION error when i'm trying to calculate Truck route, and the Car routing still works fine.

Comment: Did you re-use an older permission key? You may want to generate a new one for v3.3 to gain access to the new feature.

Comment: I'm using the permission key for v3.3.

Comment: That should be it, SDK 3.3 with a v3.3 permission key and latest map data should be working.

Comment: but still i'm getting the invalid operation error for offline truck route calculation. Online truck route calculation and offline car route calculation still works fine. Where can i find an example/sample for offline truck route calculation?

Comment: Are you using a licensed company or still in evaluation? I would suggest you submit a ticket to our support group so we can check the permission key for you.

Comment: @DavidLeong I have the same problem as Attila. I have the current offline map installed and I'm using SDK version 3.5. We are still using an evaluation key. Do you remember what the problem in this case was? Where can I submit a ticket for the support team?