# HERE offline truck routing on Android

Tags: android, here-api

We have a problem in connection with the Android SDK of HERE.
We are developing an application with offline truck navigation, which seems to be not working. When we try to use it we always get INVALID_OPERATION. The online truck routing and the offline car routing works, but the offline truck routing does not. We use the version 3.8 of the Android SDK.

We have found [this old question about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527059/android-here-sdk-offline-truck-routing-gives-no-connectivity-error), but there was no solution and we hope it is already solved now.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message 'INVALID_OPERATION' indicates that your keys are not enabled for the premium content like offline truck routing.

Comment: We used an evaluation key for the premium android SDK. We have just registered a new project with the new Freemium plan, and it works now. Thank you for the tip. By the way, I think this is a quite strange behaviour of the HERE licenses.